# Connection timeout when accessing Github

Tags: ubuntu, dns, github, connection

I have some weird problems. When I try to **log in** my **Github** account, I get a "net::**ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**" error.

I **tried with Chrome, Firefox and Opera**. In Firefox, if a clean the cache and offline data, it works for a while. Then I can log in, but I still can't create a Github repository, even if I clear the cache again.

My **friend**, in the **same network**, with Windows, **can** do whatever he wants on Github's web site, but I can't. I **tried** many **DNS** servers, I tried not to set it (my friend doesn't), but it's still **not working**.

My OS: **Ubuntu x64 12.04**

Ideas, please. And thanks.

Comment: Incorrect MTU settings can be a common cause of this error -- have you changed your MTU settings?

Comment: same problem here! really really really really weird!!

Comment: @cjc343 I tried to change my MTU settings but did not work.

Comment: Continues here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/218728/connection-timeout-when-accessing-github